# How to Display a Non-Windows App Inside a Windows App

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I embed a non-native application (application installed in windows 7) in a windows form using `c#`.

What I have tried so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Process process = new Process();


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // panel1.Container.Add(process);
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
         string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plan-G v3.2.0"), "Plan-G3.exe");
         process = Process.Start(path);

         Debug.WriteLine(process.MainWindowHandle);
         while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
             Thread.Sleep(1000); // Don't hog the CPU
            process.Refresh(); // You need this since `MainWindowHandle` is cached


        }

        Form1.SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);

        SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);

        MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel1.Width - 90, panel1.Height, true);

    }
}
```

I am able to get this to work sometimes when I start with `debugging`.

But when i start without `debugging`, the application always opens outside of the form. I don't understand why this happens.

I have also tried the `[ForceForegroundWindow][1]`() workaround.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible?

Based on other forum answers, it seems it might not be...

Comment: if you are debugging with elevated permissions, then this could be an explanation of why you see differing behaviour

Comment: I meant when I place breakpoints and choose Start With Debug options, it works sometimes but choosing Start Without Debugging always causes separate windows

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "it is technically legal. It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree"